# How might I remove duplicate lines from a file?

Tags: python, text, file-io

I have a file with one column. How to delete repeated lines in a file?

Answer (score 85):

On Unix/Linux, use the `uniq` command, as per David Locke's answer, or `sort`, as per William Pursell's comment.

If you need a Python script:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

**Update:** The `sort`/`uniq` combination will remove duplicates but return a file with the lines sorted, which may or may not be what you want. The Python script above won't reorder lines, but just drop duplicates. Of course, to get the script above to sort as well, just leave out the `outfile.write(line)` and instead, immediately after the loop, do `outfile.writelines(sorted(lines_seen))`.

Comment: You need to run sort before you run uniq because uniq will only remove lines if they're identical to the previous line.

Comment: Yes - I referred to your answer but didn't reiterate that it was sort followed by uniq.

Comment: +1 for this solution.  One further enhancement might be to store the md5 sum of the line, and compare the current line's md5 sum.  This should significantly cut down on the memory requirements.  (see http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html)

Comment: +1 I could have written this code myself but why write when you can google :)

Comment: This answer give `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort and unique.py", line 5, in <module>
    outfile.write(line)
MemoryError
` how to resolve it

Comment: @VinaySajip understand that you need to add something that you want to delete into `lines_seen = set()`. What if I have a line `Word Syllable Phone` how exactly should I do it?

Comment: Is this still the best answer in 2021?

Answer (score 46):

If you're on *nix, try running the following command:

```
sort <file name> | uniq
```

Comment: got memory leaking on a 3GB file. used 30GB of my 32GB RAM

Comment: the command dumps all lines into terminal, in order to save them into a file instead use `>>` like `sort <file path> | uniq >> <new file path>`

Answer (score 26):

```
uniqlines = set(open('/tmp/foo').readlines())
```

this will give you the list of unique lines.

writing that back to some file would be as easy as:

```
bar = open('/tmp/bar', 'w').writelines(uniqlines)

bar.close()
```

Comment: True, but the lines will be in some random order according to how they hash.

Comment: The problem with this code is that after you write, and the last line does not have an '\n'.
Then the output results will have one lines with merged 2 lines.

Comment: your solution is good for smaller files. where file size is upto 300mb or 400mb. not beyond that.

Answer (score 8):

get all your lines in the list and make a set of lines and you are done.
for example,

```
>>> x = ["line1","line2","line3","line2","line1"]
>>> list(set(x))
['line3', 'line2', 'line1']
>>>
```

If you need to preserve the ordering of lines - as set is unordered collection - try this:

```
y = []
for l in x:
    if l not in y:
        y.append(l)
```

and write the content back to the file.

Comment: True, but the lines will be in some random order according to how they hash.

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
import os
os.system("awk '!x[$0]++' /path/to/file > /path/to/rem-dups")
```

Here You are using bash into python :)

You have also other way:

```
with open('/tmp/result.txt') as result:
        uniqlines = set(result.readlines())
        with open('/tmp/rmdup.txt', 'w') as rmdup:
            rmdup.writelines(set(uniqlines))
```

Answer (score 6):

Its a rehash of whats already been said here - here what I use.

```
import optparse

def removeDups(inputfile, outputfile):
        lines=open(inputfile, 'r').readlines()
        lines_set = set(lines)
        out=open(outputfile, 'w')
        for line in lines_set:
                out.write(line)

def main():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog ' +\
                        '-i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
        parser.add_option('-i', dest='inputfile', type='string',
                        help='specify your input file')
        parser.add_option('-o', dest='outputfile', type='string',
                        help='specify your output file')
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        inputfile = options.inputfile
        outputfile = options.outputfile
        if (inputfile == None) or (outputfile == None):
                print parser.usage
                exit(1)
        else:
                removeDups(inputfile, outputfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 4):

**Python One liners :**

```
python -c "import sys; lines = sys.stdin.readlines(); print ''.join(sorted(set(lines)))" < InputFile > OutputFile
```

Answer (score 4):

adding to @David Locke's answer, with *nix systems you can run

```
sort -u messy_file.txt > clean_file.txt
```

which will create `clean_file.txt` removing duplicates in alphabetical order.

Comment: This would remove duplicates, but modify (sort) the order of the lines. Not exactly what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

> Look at script I created to remove duplicate emails from text files. Hope this helps!

```
# function to remove duplicate emails
def remove_duplicate():
    # opens emails.txt in r mode as one long string and assigns to var
    emails = open('emails.txt', 'r').read()
    # .split() removes excess whitespaces from str, return str as list
    emails = emails.split()
    # empty list to store non-duplicate e-mails
    clean_list = []
    # for loop to append non-duplicate emails to clean list
    for email in emails:
        if email not in clean_list:
            clean_list.append(email)
    return clean_list
    # close emails.txt file
    emails.close()
# assigns no_duplicate_emails.txt to variable below
no_duplicate_emails = open('no_duplicate_emails.txt', 'w')

# function to convert clean_list 'list' elements in to strings
for email in remove_duplicate():
    # .strip() method to remove commas
    email = email.strip(',')
    no_duplicate_emails.write(f"E-mail: {email}\n")
# close no_duplicate_emails.txt file
no_duplicate_emails.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a solution that uses a hashing and is a little more flashy, this is what I currently use:

```
def remove_duplicate_lines(input_path, output_path):

    if os.path.isfile(output_path):
        raise OSError('File at {} (output file location) exists.'.format(output_path))

    with open(input_path, 'r') as input_file, open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
        seen_lines = set()

        def add_line(line):
            seen_lines.add(line)
            return line

        output_file.writelines((add_line(line) for line in input_file
                                if line not in seen_lines))
```

Comment: What is the point of adding the HASH of the line to the set when you could just add the line itself?

Answer (score 2):

edit it within the same file

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen

with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i in d:
        if i not in lines_seen:
            f.write(i)
            lines_seen.add(i)
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 2):

Readable and Concise

```py
with open('sample.txt') as fl:
    content = fl.read().split('\n')

content = set([line for line in content if line != ''])

content = '\n'.join(content)

with open('sample.txt', 'w') as fl:
    fl.writelines(content)
```

Comment: it's better to use with open context manager to open the file so that it's closed safely. Also reading the whole in one go may not work if the file is big.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
f = open('temp.txt','w+')
flag = False
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for temp in f:
            if temp == line:
                flag = True
                print('Found Match')
                break
        if flag == False:
            f.write(line)
        elif flag == True:
            flag = False
        f.seek(0)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <filename> | grep '^[a-zA-Z]+$' | sort -u > outfile.txt
```

To filter and remove duplicate values from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
d = input("your file:") #write your file name here
file1 = open(d, mode="r")
file2 = open('file2.txt', mode='w')
file2 = open('file2.txt', mode='a')
file1row = file1.readline()


while file1row != "" :
    file2 = open('file2.txt', mode='a')
    file2read = open('file2.txt', mode='r')
    file2r = file2read.read().strip()
    if file1row not in file2r:
        file2.write(file1row)   
    file1row = file1.readline()
    file2read.close()
    file2.close
```