# Python unique lines

Tags: python

Hi I have a text file in the following format:

```
Sam
John
Peter
Sam 
Peter
John
```

I want to extract the unique records using REGULAR EXPRESSION from the file such as:

```
Sam
John
Peter
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You don't need regular expressions... use a set

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get unique values from a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file

Answer (score 6):

Use set:

```
In [1]: name="""
   ...: Sam
   ...: John
   ...: Peter
   ...: Sam 
   ...: Peter
   ...: John"""

In [2]: print name

Sam
John
Peter
Sam 
Peter
John

In [3]: a=name.split()

In [4]: a
Out[4]: ['Sam', 'John', 'Peter', 'Sam', 'Peter', 'John']

In [5]: set(a)
Out[5]: {'John', 'Peter', 'Sam'}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..but i want the same output using regular expressions in python

Comment: @Prashant Do you know what regular expressions are? This isn't a problem that can be solved by them.

Comment: @l4mpi You mean "this isn't a problem that *should* be solved by them". They can actually solve this.

Comment: @Veedrac no, I actually meant "can't solve this". Finding duplicates is outside of the domain of regular languages, which is what I think of when I hear "regular expression". I know that there's backreferences etc, and with this RE are actually able to process far more than regular languages, but that's not a "real" regular expression in my view. And using RE for non-regular things is probably always hackish at best and stupid at worst... (I still upvoted your answer though, appreciate the humor ^^)

Answer (score 5):

Don't listen to them!

*Of course* this can be done in Regex. Never mind that they have the correct, `O(1)` solution that's readable and concise, or that any Regex solution will be at least quadratic-time and about as readable as a drunkard's scrawling.

What matters is that it's Regex, and Regex *must* be good. Here you go:

```
re.findall(r"""(?ms)^([^\n]*)$(?!.*^\1$)""", target_string)
#>>> ['Sam', 'Peter', 'John']
```

Answer (score 4):

seems like you want to create a list by splitting the input by new line and then removing duplicates using `set()`. you can then convert that to a list using `list()`.  looks something like below. The `strip()` is used to remove the newline characters.

```
names = list(set([x.strip() for x in open('names.txt').readlines()]))
```