# File parsing in python- removing duplicates and getting index of duplicate to rearrange

Tags: python

I have a file with some duplicates, i want to find the duplicate and write to another file where duplicates are grouped together and previous lines are re-arranged. Lines are in groups of 2, so if i have duplicate in line 2 and 10, i get rid of line

```
line 1= "string1"
line2 (possibly_common_string)  or string 2
....
line9 string9 
line10 (possibly_common_string) or string 110
```

If theres no duplicates, i want to write as it is, if theres duplciates, i want to write to another file as-

```
line1 = string1
line2= common string- this was string in line 2. Old line 10 deleted.
line3= string 9 -> line 9 moved up.
line4= old line 5.
```

I am thinking of reading the whole file, looking for duplicates, but something like this loses duplicates without giving me the index from which to move from

[How might I remove duplicate lines from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file)

Can I grab the index of the duplicate line?

Comment: Why are you moving line 9 up in the output?

Comment: its associated with the duplicate line, line 10 . All lines make meaining in the file in groups of 2

Comment: It's too confusing as-written, can you give a complete sample input and output with all possible corner cases (e.g. 1st line of a pair is dupe of 2nd line of another pair, both 2nd lines are dupes, there are 3 dupes in the file, etc.)

Comment: i just solved it i think, will post solution in a couple of hours. Thanks !