# Removal of duplicate lines from a text file using python

Tags: python, duplicates

Earlier I wrote the code for extracting a specific string from multiple files and the result is stored in a separate file.Now this file has duplicate results which I need to remove .

```
import glob
import re
import os.path
path=r"H:\sample"
file_array=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.txt'))
with open("aiq_hits.txt","w") as out_file;
    for input_filename in file_array:
        with open(input_filename) as in_file:
            for line in in_file:
                match=re.findall(r"""(?<=')[^']*\.aiq(?=')|(?<=")[^"]*\.aiq(?=")""")                  
                for item in match:
                    out_file.write("%s\n" %item)
out_file.close()
```

This out_file has duplicate results which I need to remove and result should be the same file

Comment: Show some code.  What's the question?

Comment: Same question was asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file
You could try searching for what you want before posting a question

Comment: I have tried those codes but they dont work

Answer (score 5):

1. **Load** input file.
2. **Read** input file by lines. The `readlines` will return a list of lines from the file content.
3. Create a new list.
4. **Iterate** every line from the `lines`.
5. **Strip** the white spaces from the `line`.
6. **Check** if the line is present in `new_lines`.
7. If not, then **append** the `line` in the `new_lines` list.
8. **Write** `new_lines` into the file.

Demo:

```
input_file = "input.txt"
with open(input_file, "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        #- Strip white spaces
        line = line.strip()
        if line not in new_lines:
            new_lines.append(line)

output_file = "output.txt"
with open(output_file, "w") as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join(new_lines))
```

Comment: :Thanks for the suggestion but I need output in input file only

Comment: Also the result is in one horizontal line

Comment: 1: use input file name during write file event. i.e. `with open(input_file, "wb") as fp:` and 2. not getting?? lines are on new lines.. you can shear you code with us on stackoverflow or email me vivekbsable@gmail.com