# Finding and deleting duplicate lines in a file(the fastest and most efficient way)

Tags: python

As the title says, I want to find and delete duplicate lines in a file. That is pretty easy to do...the catch is that i want to know what is the fastest and most efficient way to do that (let's say that you have gigabytes worth of files and you want to do this as efficient and as fast as you can)

If you know some method...as complicated as it is that can do that I would like to know. I heard some stuff like loop unrolling and started to second guess that the most simple things are the fastest so I am curious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I remove duplicate lines from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file)

Comment: Check this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix

Comment: I don't see any of the answers in the threads you linked deal with matters of performance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: if doing it with python is not a strict requirement then `uniq file_with_dupes > file_without_dupes` is perhaps the easiest and fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is the keep a set of the lines seen so far, and return only the ones not in it. This approach is used in python's collections implementation

```
def unique_lines(filename):
   lines = open(filename).readlines()
   seen = set()

   for line in lines:
       if line not in seen:
           yield line
           seen.add(line)
```

and then

```
for unique_line in unique_lines(filename)
    # do stuff
```

Of course, if you don't care about the order, you can convert the whole text to a set directly, like

```
set(open(filename).readlines())
```

Comment: Wouldn't `open(filename).readlines()` create a list in memory with all the lines? It doesn't seem memory eficient. You can do this instead: `f = open(filename); for line in f: ...`. Also, it's best practice to use a `with` statement when dealing with files.

Answer (score 0):

Use python `hashlib` to hash every line in file to a unique hash... And check if a line is duplicate, lookup into the hashes in a `set`

Lines can be kept directly in a `set`, however, hashing will reduce space required.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html