# Issue with writing multiple lines into a file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to download multiple specific links(images´ urls) into a txt file(or any file where all links can be listed underneath each others).

I get them but the code wrtite each link on the top of the other one and at the end it stays only a link :(. Also I want not repeated urls

```
def dlink(self, image_url):
        r = self.session.get(image_url, stream=True)
        with open('Output.txt','w') as f:
            f.write(image_url + '\n')
```

Comment: How does the output looks like? I mean, the txt

Comment: The txt file keeps only a link: https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/groups/loader.gif

Comment: And the parameter, image_url , is just a url? or a list with all urls?

Comment: A list of all the needed urls

Comment: I see, let me know if my answer works fine for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit

Huge mistake of my part, as it is a method, and you will call it several times, if you open it in write mode ('w') or similar, it will Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. 
 So, if you use the 'a' way, you can see that:

> Opens a file for appending. The file pointer is at the end of the file
>   if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If the
>   file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.

The other problem radics in image_url is a list, so you need to write it line by line:

```
def dlink(self, image_url):
        r = self.session.get(image_url, stream=True)
        with open('Output.txt','a') as f:
            for url in list(set(image_url)):
                f.write(image_url + '\n')
```

another way to do it:

```
your_file = open('Output.txt', 'a')
r = self.session.get(image_url, stream=True)
for url in list(set(image_url)):
  your_file.write("%s\n" % url)
your_file.close() #dont forget close it :)
```

Comment: DVoter, I need a little  information of why you downvoted please, so I can see the mistake and can learn also

Comment: No need for `+` in the mode

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes thank you, I notice that reading a little more, I have never been in this kind of situation, and didn't count that it was a method, so it could be call more than once, causing those issues, I edited the answer

Comment: I did not DVoted any answer, i appreciate all of them. And now it works as it should :)

Comment: @TTT haha no no, I now you didn't :), and you can't even if you want to, you can only upvote for now, and accept answers, I said that to the user who did, but I don't know who is it, but there is no need to

Comment: @TTT don't forget accept the answer that fixed the problem! Only one you can, is a good practice, with the check box top left in the answer, and good luck! I have always loved to help ;)

Comment: @DamianLattenero just one thing in the newly created txt file the same link comes several times, how to exclude that ?. i mean that the link comes only once

Comment: @TTT you can use  `for url in list(set(image_url)):` , don't forget to vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I will accept your answer because it helped me the most and for cleaning the list the answered there helped me more: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file

Answer (score 3):

The issue is most simply that opening a file with mode `'w'` truncates any existing file. You should change `'w'` to `'a'` instead. This will open an existing file for writing, but append instead of truncating.

More fundamentally, the problem may be that you are opening the file over and over in a loop. This is very inefficient. The only time the approach you use could be really useful is if your program is approaching the OS-imposed limit on number of open files. If this is not the case, I would recommended putting the loop inside the `with` block, keeping the mode as `'w'` since you open the file just once now, and passing the open file to your `dlink` function.

Comment: I see... thanks for sharing, good info here, is a plus one for teaching

Answer (score 2):

the file open mode is wrong，'w' mode make this file  was overwritten every time you open it,not appended to it. replace it to 'a' mode.

you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566951/8178794 for more detail

Comment: Suggest fix please

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, please flag it as duplicate and do not simply link to the other answer.

Comment: Nice Iaixiong, I Din't notice that if this is not a method executed only one time, it could be a huge mistake to choose bad the mode of the file, is a plus one in my opinion, the OP never ask about the mode

Answer (score 0):

Open a file with option `w` overwrite the file if existring, use the mode `a` to append data to an existing file.

Try :

```
import requests
from os.path import splitext


# use mode='a' to append result without erasing filename
def dlink(url, filename, mode='w'):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        return
    # here the link is valid
    with open(filename, mode) as desc:
        desc.write(url)


def dimg(img_url, img_name):
    r = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        return
    _, ext = splitext(img_url)
    with open(img_name + ext, 'wb') as desc:
        for chunk in r:
            desc.write(chunk)


dlink('https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg', 'links.txt')
dlink('https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg', 'links.txt', 'a')

dimg('https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg', 'freepik')
```

Comment: Hi, I think the issue also is in the mode of the file, check the other answers and you will see :)