# How to delete or skip a list of lines in a text file and print the remaining lines in a new text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python. I am trying to  create a script that prints lines of text to a text file that exclude a list of lines. Is the error `IndexError : List index out of range` due to the `.pop` function?

```
with open(file_path) as f:

    lines = []
    lines = open(f,'r').readlines() 

    # delete the following lines from the textfile
    skip_line =[14,27,39,56,78]

    while skip_line:
        pop = skip_line.pop(0)
        print(pop)
        print(lines[pop])

        lines.remove(lines[pop])

        with open('duplicates_removed.txt', 'w') as savefile:
                savefile.writelines(lines)
        savefile.close()
```

I expect that the lines found in `lines[pop]` will be removed from `lines`.

Actual result:

```
IndexError : List index out of range
```

Comment: Please include some sample text as well as the full error message (traceback). Most likely your test file has fewer lines than indicated in `skip_line`. Also note that you're opening the file two times and saving the other during each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: The line `lines = open(f,'r').readlines()` is wrong and I'm surprised it doesn't raise an error. You already opened the file on the first line, you can just do `f.readlines()` but the pythonic way is to do `for line in f: do_something(line)`.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it. After you delete the first line in `lines`, all the line indexes in `skip_line` that come after it are off by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
skip_lines = {14, 27, 39, 56, 78}

with open(filepath) as infile:
    with open("duplicates_removed.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for index, line in enumerate(infile):
            if index not in skip_lines:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: If you want to detect duplicate lines using Python instead of making a list of line numbers by hand, you should check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file) or the dozens of others just like it.