# Remove duplicate pages from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm cracking my head around this problem.

I have a list of urls and I want to keep the firstr unique url per php page.

So example input:

- http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1
- http://www.example.com/index.php?id=2
- http://www.example.com/page.php?id=2
- http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1

Example Output:

- http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1
- http://www.example.com/page.php?id=2

So it must clean a file and only output one url per unique page.

Comment: any code that you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How might I remove duplicate lines from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215208/how-might-i-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url either yourself with regex/split() or with url parser package like `urllib.parse`

Store `path`(page) in a `dict` (it will give you fast lookup `O(n)` on average) and see if its not already there,if not then add `page` as key and `url` as value.

Take dict values, it will give you unique urls only

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

list_url = [
"http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1",
"http://www.example.com/index.php?id=2",
"http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1",
"http://www.example.com/page.php?id=2",
"blog.example.com/page.php?id=2",
  "subdomain.example.com/folder/page.php?id=2"
 ]

mydict = {}
for url in list_url:
    url_parsed =urlparse(url)
    path = url_parsed.path
    
    if path not in mydict:
        mydict[path] = url
```

Taking dictionary value and converting to list

```
 print(list(mydict.values()))
```

as @waps converted this to similar but list_comphension structure, you can do it if having first id is not your concern.

```
list({ urlparse(url).path:url for url in list_url }.values())
```

Output

```
['http://www.example.com/index.php?id=2',
```

'http://www.example.com/page.php?id=2',
'blog.example.com/page.php?id=2',
'subdomain.example.com/folder/page.php?id=2']

Comment: Thanks, seems logical.. But what about adding these two urls to the list:

"http://blog.example.com/page.php?id=2",
"http://subdomain.example.com/folder/page.php?id=2"

Those are also unique, but when I add these to the list the original http://www.example.com/page?id=1 is not added

Comment: Always try to provide all possible scenarios.

Comment: For the question, it was tricky to be judge. I do close questions myself when there is a need. Question was looking well-asked (had inputs and outputs) and problem(removing 2nd occurrence of url ). Moreover, we need to be nice to new comers.